# Is there any way that I can put the subscript and superscript at the back of a symbol?

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, superscripts

Obviously, I can use `X^s` or `X_s` to put a symbol `s` as superscript (`X^s`) or subscript (`X_s`) in front of another symbol `X`.

What about the case with `s` at the back of `X`? `_s X` or `^s X` gives something like what I mean (`$_s X$` and `$^s X$`) but they don't seem very nice as there is a space between symbols.

Comment: Try $X_s$ $X^s$ $\vphantom{X}_sX$ $\vphantom{X}^s\!X$.

Comment: what you call back and front I would actually call the other way around

Comment: @IvoBeckers: Agree. How about _before_ (prefix) and _after_ (postfix). And let's ignore _back_ and _front_ altogether. I was going to mention _suffix_ but that's another can of worms.

Answer (score 11):

If all you need to do is place an occasional prefix sub- or superscript, you could simply write

```
${}_s S$ and ${}^t T$
```

to generate

[image]

If your typesetting needs are a bit more demanding, you could make use of the [tensor](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tensor/) package. The preceding screenshot could also have been generated by

```
$\tensor[_s]{S}{}$ and $\tensor[^t]U{}$
```

The package's `\tensor` and `\tensor*` macros are very versatile indeed. Do have a look at the package's user guide for an in-depth review of what these macros can do.